Confusion on forward process of diffusion models
I'm reading Chp 20 of Deep Learning Foundations and Concepts and am having trouble understanding how these two equations are derived.
For context
$$
(1) \ \ q(z_t|z_{t-1})=\mathscr{N}(z_t|\sqrt{\beta_t}x,(1-\beta_t)\mathbb{I})
$$
The joint distribution of the latent variables, conditioned on the observed data vector x is given by
$$ 
(2) \ \ q(z_1,...,z_t|x)=q(z_1|x)\prod_{\tau=2}^tq(z_\tau|z_{\tau-1})
$$
If we now marginalize over the intermediate variables $z_1,...,z_t$, we obtain the diffusion kernel:
$$
(3) \ \ q(z_t|x)=\mathscr{N}(z_t|\sqrt{\alpha_t}x,(1-\alpha_t)\mathbb{I})
$$
with $\alpha_t = \prod_{\tau=1}^t(1-\beta_\tau)$.
I understand that $z_t$ is only dependent on $z_{t-1}$ because of the markov process assumption but I don't understand how to mathematically prove the LHS = RHS of (2).
What is meant by "marginalizing over the intermediate variables"? I know by the reparameterization trick we can write (1) as
$$
z_t = \sqrt{\beta_t}z_{t-1} + \sqrt{1-\beta_t}\epsilon_t
$$
with $\epsilon_t\sim\mathscr{N}(\epsilon_t|0,I)$, so my naive first thought on how to show (3) is by substituting
$$
z_{t-1}=\sqrt{\beta_{t-1}}z_{t-2} + \sqrt{1-\beta_{t-1}}\epsilon_{t-1} 
$$
into $z_t$ which gives
$$
z_t=\sqrt{\beta_t\beta_{t-1}}z_{t-2}+\sqrt{\beta_{t}(1-\beta_{t-1})}\epsilon_{t-1}+\sqrt{1-\beta_t}\epsilon_t
$$
but I don't understand how repeated substitution leads to (3).
Another side question I have is whether the reparameterization trick gives an exact representation of (1) or is it just an approximation. My apologies if I didn't ask this question properly this is my first time using stack exchange.
